# What is the 'f' used for in JBox-2d?

Tags: java, box2d, jbox2d

It seems to be used in value declarations in the engine but the documentation of JBox-2D does not explain what this 'unit' is. Example:

```
float x = 20.0f //<-- this 'f'

FixtureDef fixDef = new FixtureDef();
fixDef.shape = shape;
fixDef.density = 0.0f; //<-- this 'f'
fixDef.friction = 0.9f; //<-- this 'f'
```

What is it? If it is indeed a unit, what is it relative to? What benefit does it have for the engine?

**EDIT:**
What use does it have for the engine? Is there any benefit to using a float opposed to a double?

Comment: 'f' appended to a literal number just indicates that it's a float value (instead of a double). (It has nothing to do with JBox - it's just Java syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is no unit, `f` indicates that the number is a `float`.

If you just write `0.1` for example, you will get an error because `0.1` will be parsed as a `double` value. The compiler needs the instruction that the value is desired a float. That's what's the `f` for.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: I have tested your assertion that leaving out "f" will produce an error and the program continues to run.

Comment: @ylun The instruction `float x = 3.1;` should not compile; however you can use also `3.1` when the value is not explicitely a float value, then it is compiled as a `double`.

Comment: `jDef.maxMotorTorque = 45;` What is your opinion on this code? I feel confused as to why it must be defined to a float.

Comment: So then I misunderstood you, sorry. What I wrote is valid for decimal (floating point) numbers. If you have an integer ("whole number") as `45` it is treated as an integer value (since it has no floating point `.`). Integers can be casted to floats without problems since your value can't lose presision. Therefore you can omit the `f` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It indicates that the value is a float literal.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: What use does it have in the engine? Why would it be better to declare a float instead of a double?

Comment: No idea. Possibly performance, possibly just an arbitrary or wrong design decision.

Comment: why must a value be indicated as a float if the variable has been declared as a float (for example, this line: `float x = 20.0f`)?